# ASP.NET - How do I stop classes/dlls from one project being compiled into another project

Tags: asp.net

I have one of those annoying problems where something that used to work stopped working.
Check out this code:

```
Assembly _abc_assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(“c:\junk\abcabstract\bin\abc.dll”);

ABC.ContentAttribute attribute;
attribute = (ABC.ContentAttribute)_abc_assembly.CreateInstance("ABC.TextAttribute");
```

ContentAttribute is defined in the dll.
Obviously, this should work. You should be able to cast an object to itself.

But it produces this error:

[alt text http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/compile1.png](http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/compile1.png)

This bug is discussed here http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/plugin.html which is how I got even this far. From this post I gather that the class ContentAttribute is somehow ending up in ABC.DLL **and** the website project's DLL.

The website project I have looks like this:

[alt text http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/compile2.png](http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/compile2.png)

Now ContentAttribute is not in this project, it is in the dll ABC.DLL. You can see that as I have expanded every branch and the file ContentAttribute.cs is not there.

Yet somehow it is ending up in the dll for the website creating a duplicating reference. ContentAttribute is somehow ending up in ABC.DLL and the website project's DLL.

Can anyone tell me:

a) Why is ContentAttribute in two dlls? I didn’t think including a dll in a project forced that code into the projects DLL.

b) How to stop it from happening?

By the way, I definitely don't want to change the website project into a website application if I can avoid it.

Notes:

Deleting the temporary ASP.NET files does not work. As soon as I compile my website project they get recreated.

[alt text http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/compile3.png](http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/compile3.png)

Answer (score 0):

ABC.DLL is referenced by your website and it becomes part of it (it is in Bin folder). ASP.NET compiles your website and ABC.DLL is placed in temp location (C:\Windows...\Temporary ASP.NET Filse...). It gets loaded by ASP.NET automatically. You are trying to load ABC.DLL manually from different location (D:\junk\abcabstract\bin\abc.dl). Two assemblies do not match hence you get the error.

To stop this from happening you have to rethink your plugin architecture I guess. Can you give more information?

**Update**:
Why don't you fix it like this:

```
// Assembly _abc_assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(“c:\junk\abcabstract\bin\abc.dll”);
// ContentAttribute attribute;
// attribute = (ContentAttribute)_abc_assembly.CreateInstance("ABC.TextAttribute");
ContentAttribute attribute = new ContentAttribute();
```

Comment: I could swear this wasn't happening a day ago. There is no real architecture here yet, it's a test project, I just need it to work!

Comment: Why you need to load assembly using full path? I added code that creates ContentAttribute instance without reflection.

Comment: I need to examine classes using reflection and cast certain types back to a base type as I perform certain operations. The code above is not realistic but clearly points out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a namespace collision. It doesnt know which ContentAttribute to use since it is finding 2 in different namespaces/assemblies.

You may have an old copy of the DLL named differently. Delete your temporary ASP.Net directories and recompile.

To avoid in the future:

Use fully qualified names for your objects if you need to get it to work.

```
ABC.ContentAttribute ca = new ABC.ContentAttribute();
```

or if casting do the same

```
ABC.ContentAttribute ca =(ABC.ContentAttribute)ca2;
```

Comment: I have added fully qualified names and deleted all temporary files but it still doesn't work. See my updated question.

Comment: this could be a dumb question, but in your code at the top you are calling load from "C:\" while the project is in the "D:\" drive. and since you are casting TextAttribute, i assume it inherits from ContentAttribute or that wouldnt work. And the error message leads me to believe you should be looking in the Default.aspx.cs which I do not see in your project. Maybe its hidden, click the "show hidden files" at the top of the solution explorer.